# How to return "if" in a if loop?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

Hi guys actually first I wanted to do this loop.

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("etcProgram.bin")[0];
                foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule moz in p.Modules)
                    if (csh.Text == "csh" || bin.Text == "bin")
                    {
                        if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("csh") != -1)
                        {
                            csh.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();
                        }
                        if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("bin") != -1)
                        {
                            bin.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                else
                    {
                      !!!!!! return to "if" until "if code" happens !!!!!!
                    }
```

But my poor code knowledge can't come through this problem. So I wrote nearly same thinh with **timer**. Then I wrote this code.

```
 private void tmrActive_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Wolfteam.bin")[0];
                foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule moz in p.Modules)
                    if (csh.Text == "csh" || bin.Text == "bin")
                    {
                        if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("csh") != -1)
                        {
                            csh.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();
                        }
                        if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("bin") != -1)
                        {
                            bin.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                else
                    {
                        tmrActive.Stop();
                        MessageBox.Show("It's stopped");
                    }
            }
```

But I saw that MessageBox appears 5-6 times when I started this.And I dont know why. So I dont feel very safe about use this code.

1- Do you know what's the problem with that timer. Shouldn't this messagebox appear once?

2- Can you help me about the code without timer.Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: What about a while loop?

Comment: You're missing { after your foreach and ending with } after the else. It's not required but it helps readability. And it's notmal to get it 1 time per module , you're doing it in the foreach module (in the else) since the if/else is not dependant on the module (you're checking on bin.text and csh.text but not moz) then if you have 5-6 modules you will always have either 0 or 5-6 message boxes

Comment: an `if` statement is not a loop.  Seems worth mentioning

Comment: Side note: your code (and solutions offered so far) will freeze your form. You may want to read on "long loop freezes/hangs window"...

Comment: You need to use recursive methods , try googling...

Comment: Alright thank you all guys :) So its because of the modules. But when I changed the code like                                                                                      `                        MessageBox.Show("test");
                        tmrActive.Stop();
                        break;`                                 Its always shows me mesagge boxes . But when i change the code like that `                        tmrActive.Stop();
                        MessageBox.Show("test");
                        break;`               Its just show one message box that I want.

Comment: I didnt get it well? Why Is it changes everything?

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like...

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule moz in p.Modules)
{
    bool breakloop = false;
    while (!breakloop)
    {
        if (csh.Text == "csh" || bin.Text == "bin")
        {
            if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("csh") != -1)
                csh.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();

            if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("bin") != -1)
                bin.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();

            breakloop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that is a little cleaner @Think2ceCode1ce.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use break statement in order to stop a loop.

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule moz in p.Modules)
{
    if (csh.Text == "csh" || bin.Text == "bin")
    {
         if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("csh") != -1)
         {
              csh.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();
         }
         if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("bin") != -1)
         {
              bin.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();
         }
         break;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this whole code as a Recursive function with a Specific condition to stop the condition whenever you want like this

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule moz in p.Modules) { looping () {


bool breakloop = false;
while (!breakloop)
{
    if (csh.Text == "csh" || bin.Text == "bin")
    {
        if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("csh") != -1)
            csh.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();

        if (moz.FileName.IndexOf("bin") != -1)
            bin.Text = moz.BaseAddress.ToString();

        breakloop = true;
        looping();
    }
}
```